# What is the purpose of setting a variable in self.send for Django Channels?

Tags: django, channel

In Django Channels [tutorial](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/part_2.html), you set a variable called 'text_message'. 
This is for the consumer to echo the message that it has received.

```
def receive(self, text_data):
    text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
    message = text_data_json['message']

    self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
        'message': message
    }))
```

**What is the use of 'text_message'?**

I have removed it so that it looks like this, and still successfully rendered the message in my HTML.

```
def receive(self, text_data):
    text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
    message = text_data_json['message']

    self.send(json.dumps({
        'message': message
        }))
```

Comment: There's no variables being set here. That's just a keyword argument.